# Camera Collision in Three.js

Tags: three.js

Does anyone know how can I perform a simple collision check to push back camera so that it doesn't "go through" scene? Is it possible to make a camera respect the 3D objects "masses"? I'm trying to make a small simulator to fly around a building, and enter some rooms, but the camera will always go inside objects.

Comment: possible duplicate of [camera and terrain collision on three.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14931687/camera-and-terrain-collision-on-three-js)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can set 3 raycasters for each 3D directions. You append them and the camera to an empty object that you move (not the camera) so everything moves at once.

When your raycasters intersects something you make the difference between the intersection point coordinates and the empty object position. This gives you all the information you can need.

If you want to define objects parameters like masses, add them to `object.userData` and access them via the returned intersection array.

Comment: Before I dive into it, a quick question: is it reasonable for a pre-loaded scene? It will be a single scene; will it work or will it be too power-consuming to check collisions against all objects?

Comment: raycasters use resources but 3 is reasonable, no matter how much objects your scene has. You can imagine different solutions. Right now i think a lighter solution would be to remember the previous camera position at each render, and set only one raycaster in the direction of (actual-previous) positions. It all depend of your scene, if objects move too...

Comment: Objects will all be static. It will be a simple simulator to view rooms of a college complex. Thanks for the tips!